# How to trigger manually a change of the route, with react-router-v4, like <Link> do it, but manually inside a function?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm working on a project with **React** and **react-router-v4**,  and
I'm trying to find a way to trigger a change of the route manually.

something like `<Link to="/newpage">` component, which takes you to a new route.

but I want to do it manually from inside one of my methods,

something like `this.router.location = "/newpage"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using withRouter high-order component?

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

```
class GoToNewPageButton extends React.Component {
  navigateToNewPage() {
    this.props.history.push('/newpage');
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.navigateToNewPage.bind(this)}>To the new page!</button>
  }
}

const GoToNewPageWithHistory = withRouter(GoToNewPageButton);
```

Comment: I saw this one, but I wasnt really sure how to use it.

im wrapping my component with it like this:
const newComponent = withRouter(theComponent);

and then what ?

Comment: @ueeiee Then you have access to `this.props.history` so you can do `this.props.history.push('/my-route')` to programmatically redirect.

Comment: @ueeiee I have added one example of using it.

Comment: thank you for you comment @PompolutZ, 
it works great :)

Comment: @ueeiee don't forget to accept the answer if it was helpful :P

Comment: @PompolutZ thanks for letting me know, im kinda new here  :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `this.props.history.push` method that is exposed by the `<Link>` component or by the withRouter high-order component as PompolutZ mentioned in the answer above.

An example of such is `<button onClick={() => this.props.history.push('/Home') } />`

Comment: how do I exactly expose "history" to my props?
its not a default props I have, so I cant use it or to push something to it, cuz its undefined

Comment: Use the `WithRouter` Higher Order Component from React-Router to expose the history, location, and match props to your component.  
If your component is already being rendered via a Link component, these props should already be available to you.
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

Answer (score -1):

Render a Redirect component which will navigate to the new location.

```
<Redirect to="/somewhere/else"/>
```

For more details check [documentation here.](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md)